# lookupedit select by value, devexpress

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress

Is it possible to select element in lookupEdit by value ? I have valuemeber set and want to select elelemnt with specified value :)

thanks for help,
bye

Answer (score 3):

Set the editor's EditValue property to the required value to select the required element.